# autoloader conflicts, fail to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, class, autoload, autoloader

I write autoloader in my controller file to load a class file. This load class in the services folder well. But it will cause this issue when load class not in services folder.

> [2017-05-11 17:38:23] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException'
>   with message 'include(/var/www/market/app/services/ProductDomain.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in
>   /var/www/market/app/controllers/CloudController.php:27

```
public function __construct()
{
    spl_autoload_register(function($classname) {
        include app_path() . '/services/' . $classname . '.php';
    });
}
```

This may caused by confilct with other autoloader, may be laravel's autoloader. I want to know how to make my autoloader to just load class file under services folder, remaining other class files to be loaded by laravel framework's autoloader.

How to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have /var/www/market/app/services/ProductDomain.php this file? case sensitive file

Comment: Make sure `/var/www/market/app/services/ProductDomain.php` this exists?

Comment: no , this class may belong to other package installed by composer.

Comment: laravel also have autoloader, such as the class file in the controllers folder is autoloaded by another autoloader. So here the autoloader conflicts. My autoloader try to load class file not belong to the services path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by check the file exist first.  And the autoloaders have loading sequence.

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php),

> If there must be multiple autoload functions, spl_autoload_register()
>   allows for this. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions,
>   and runs through each of them in the order they are defined. By
>   contrast, __autoload() may only be defined once.

```
public function __construct()
{
    spl_autoload_register(function($classname) {
        if(file_exists(app_path() . '/services/' . $classname . '.php'))
            include app_path() . '/services/' . $classname . '.php';
    });
}
```

So my defined autoloader will load the php class before laravel framework's autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

If file physically exist, and you have correct permission on it (you can do chmod 777 for testing)  Try `composer install`, after that composer `dump-autoload -o`

Comment: I'm sure ProductDomain.php exists. But it's not in the services folder. I want my autoloader just load class files in the services folder, not other files.